How to get the underlying WebView created by the webview_flutter package
I am creating a flutter plugin for a native iOS sdk and this sdk requires a webview.
If the flutter project uses, webview_flutter package to create the webview, how can I get the underlying webview in my plugin?
In the webview_flutter_wkwebview documentation, they mentioned about, FWFWebViewFlutterWKWebViewExternalAPI to access the webview. but there is not more details about how to do that.
is it even possible to achieve this?
